# On select element adding option with onclick eventlistener failing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Under a `<select>` element trying to add options with onclick event listener, but when i add following its failing to create the options.

```
function setSouresFromField(input1,input2) {
  // large code...: for actions
}

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = sourceInfos[i].id; //works
option.text = sourceInfos[i].label;//works
option.addEventListener('click', setSourcesFromField(true, true) ); //does not work
```

Comment: `option.addEventListener('click', function(){setSourcesFromField(true, true)});` But I would have used `change` event of `select` than `click` event of `option`

Comment: Also tried the way you mentioned but still same, not working when i click option items.

Comment: Will you mind sharing a demo/fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s5hkrt66/ - please see kindly here.

Comment: [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, you are *calling* `setSourcesFromField` and setting your event listener to its return value (if any, it'll just be `undefined` if your fn does not return anything). This is more likely what you want:

```
option.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  // work with event object if necessary
  setSourcesFromField(true, true);
});
```

Comment: Aha, Rayon is totally correct, "Rather than watching <option> elements for events, you should watch for {event("change")}} events on <select>." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Minimal example of watching change: http://codepen.io/RwwL/pen/rLazEw

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() { /* do stuff here*/ }, false);
```

The last boolean parameter controls how the listener reacts to bubbling events[see [here]](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).

Comment: Well, it does work... the problem is... your problem is something else. http://jsfiddle.net/1g4fuoc7/5/